# Does moving house invalidate French cheques?

Tags: france, banking

I was looking earlier at my French cheque book, and was rather surprised to see that the cheques not only have the bank's address on them, but also mine too.

In other countries where I've had cheque books, the cheques feature my name, the bank's name, and the address of the bank branch. They have always continued to be valid when I moved, and in most cases were also valid when I switched branches but kept the same account number.

Finding my address on a French cheque was therefore a bit unexpected, and makes me wonder what happens if I move house. Do French cheques continue to be valid if you move, or will I have to notify my bank of my new address then order a brand new cheque book?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but US checks also normally have the owner's address.  I think the purpose is so that if your check bounces, the payee will have an easier time finding you to demand payment.  But it isn't used in normal payment processing - normally nobody would look at it at all.  I've used checks with old addresses and never had a problem.  But I do not know if France is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this question and I just saw that my cheques have my old address.

I think that first the cheques are not checked unless they are a big amount. Maybe their serial number are checked systematically but most likely not either the signature or maybe even date.

About your specific question regarding the address, I would say that what matters is that bank emitted the cheque. The exact address of the customer does not matter because as you pointed it's not where you live that matters but whether the bank gave you the cheque.

And by the way it is still better to update your address, banking information is considered sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can finish your cheque book with no problems with your old address. Personally I used cheque with my old address during 2 years. They don't care about that

Comment: this is the correct answer